# Missing templates from `<cmath>` header in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, standards-compliance, cmath

I just noticed that the templates dictated by the c++11 Standard **[26.8 c.math]** for the `<cmath>` header are missing from the version of the c++ standard library shipped with visual studio 2010.

In particular I was looking for std::signbit but a [search on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wsh95e5.aspx) confirmed what I was seeing in the shipped header (namely, a series of using directives which import only the "old" C names). 
I didn't recall reading about this deviation from the Standard, nor is it explicitly pointed out in the msdn documentation.

What is the best workaround to get the missing functionality?

Is there some official communication about fixing this in some future release of Visual Studio?

**EDIT**
The version of the Standard which I was referring to is outdated, so my claim of incompleteness is ill-aimed. signbit is still missing, but it's not a template, it's an overloaded function. Thanks to @Xeo for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [these aren't templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) (would be strange, as there are no templates in C and `<cmath>` is a C header).

Then, VS2010 was shipped *way* before C++11 was finished, so it's understandable that not all of the stdlib is included there.

FWIW, VS11 claims to have the whole C++11 stdlib covered.

Comment: Good news about VS11. But please note that the standard calls them templates, cmath knows about namespaces (which are not very C like). The signature of signbit is namespace std { template <class T> bool signbit(T x); }.

Comment: @Francesco: I don't know which standard paper you have, but in the FDIS, `std::signbit` is directly taken from the C stdlib, which defines three overloads (26.8/10). Also, the namespace is the point of the `<cheader>`s. :)

Comment: I am referring to the Final Draft n3092, page 970. Point 11 says "The templates defined in cmath replace the C macros with the same names. The templates have the following declarations: ...". Point 12 says: "The templates behave the same as the C macros with corresponding names". Looking at the mingw source or at the g++ sources online confirms that they are function templates (plus overloads for the usual types). See eg http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/c_global/cmath?revision=181349&view=markup

Comment: @Francesco: That's a *very very very* old paper. The latest, publicly available pre-C++11 draft is N3242. The latest post-C++11 draft is [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (which is basically C++11 standard with minor editorial fixes).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Xeo. I stand corrected (still I don't see why they got rid of the templated version).

Comment: These extra overloads may or may not be templates.

Comment: "*FWIW, VS11 claims to have the whole C++11 stdlib covered.*" Quoting [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx): "*Additionally, VC11 won't completely implement the C99 Standard Library*". So, don't expect to see `std::signbit` in VC11.